# AngularJS: Can I skip function parameters-callbacks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to javascript and Angular and want to know one thing:

for example I have used some other modules, and in their doc i saw such line of events:

```
editable.imageError (e, editor, error)
```

[here](https://editor.froala.com/events)

and in my app i am not handling the error params/callbacks, i have made some manipulations on view:

```
$scope.froalaOptions = {
  imageUploadURL: settings.apiBaseUri + '/files'
  events: {
    imageError: function(e, editor, error) {
      $scope.displayAlert('text');
    }
  }
};
```

So my question is that is it normal if i skip this params? like:

```
$scope.froalaOptions = {
  imageUploadURL: settings.apiBaseUri + '/files'
  events: {
    imageError: function() {
      $scope.displayAlert('text');
    }
  }
};
```

also the same with http get/post data like:

In this example,If I replace these codes

```
$http.put('/articles', $scope.article, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.success(function(response) {
  $scope.submittedArticle = false;
}).error(function(err, status) {
  console.log('operation failed, status: ' + status);
});
```

to:

```
$http.put('/articles', $scope.article, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.success(function() {
  $scope.submittedArticle = false;
}).error(function(status) {
  console.log('operation failed, status: ' + status);
});
```

am I on the right way or not, because automated js highlighter say me to delete unused params?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its absolutely fine to skip argument/parameter names in your function which you don't use.

As @Yoeri has mentioned in comments,

> Just don't write code you don't use

Comment: They do. He should remove those params as well. The less unused code, the better the readability. If at some point in time he needs them back.. well just add them again to the parameters. Oh and never ever ever ever use things like the arguments array unless you really know why you are doing it.

Comment: I agree to your point regarding arguments array. But I feel that changing the function signature is not a good practice. At any time in future we'll require them in our function. So why to avoid the function parameters? In case we need them in future, we may need to search the documentation to know what parameters are required which is unnecessary. But yes in terms of event handlers, i rarely define the `event` param in the function callback.

Comment: 'at any point in time' .. 'we may' ... how many bad code is written after saying those words... When you need them, you won't have enough just using the name. So you'll get to the docs anyway to know what those values actually contain. If you already know all the parameters, then you won't need the documentation to add them either. Just don't write code you don't use.

Comment: `Just don't write code you don't use` yup, that's true.